# How do I get the prompt onto a new line after executing a java application

Tags: java, terminal, command-prompt, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running Ubuntu version 22.04.

```
I've got Java running and I'm executing the following code:

class Shuffle1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        
        int x = 3;
        while (x > 0)   {
            
            if (x > 2)  {
                System.out.print("a");
            }
            
            x = x - 1;
            System.out.print("-");
            
            if (x == 2) {
                System.out.print("b c");
            }
            
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.print("d");
                x = x - 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

When I execute this code in the terminal I get the following view:
[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BYKo.png)

My question is: how do I get the prompt bit onto a new line?

Comment: use a System.out.println("") statement

Comment: don't put code in a comment. Edit your question

Comment: `System.out.println` will do it, as another comment here says. You appear to have used `System.out.print` again instead.

Comment: don't put code in comments, formatted or otherwise, edit the original question. And no, you didn't add the line I suggested

Comment: One line program: `System.out.println("a-b c-d");`

Comment: @Stultuske thanks for the patience! It now works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code according to your question. Just change the last `System.out.print("");` statement to `System.out.println();`

```
class Shuffle1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int x = 3;
        while (x > 0) {

            if (x > 2) {
                System.out.print("a");
            }
            
            x = x - 1;
            System.out.print("-");
            
            if (x == 2) {
                System.out.print("b c");
            }
            
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.print("d");
                x = x - 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```